# Zend Framework 2 - Controller instantiate Service via (modified?) Factory

Tags: zend-framework2, dependencies, factory, instantiation, strategy-pattern

I have an abstract service class `SAbstract` which is inherited by `ConcreteServiceA` and `ConcreteServiceB`. Now I am instantiating `ConcreteServiceA` in the factory class of my controller and inject the service in my controller.

In a specific action in my controller I want to exchange `ConcreteServiceA` with `ConcreteServiceB` to change behavior. Because they have same interface (abstract class `SAbstract`) I could inject it in my controller as well (the services are a Strategy-Pattern).

But I don't want to instantiate `ConcreteServiceB` directly in my controller to keep my code clean (for easy refactoring and exchanging behavior).

A possible solution is to create a second factory for my controller which injects `ConcreteServiceB` instead of `ConcreteServiceA` but then I have duplicated lots of code which is not good...
Another solution would be to inject both services in my controller (but this "smells" like bad code).

Is [a delegator factory](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.delegator-factories.html) the right way to do this? Then I have to implement setters in my controller...

Is there a better way?

I tried to schematically visualize my class relationships.

```
AbstractService <|--<inherit>- ConcreteServiceA
AbstractService <|--<inherit>- ConcreteServiceB
Controller -<use>--> AbstractService
Controller:ActionA -<use>--> ConcreteServiceA:exportAction()
Controller:ActionB -<use>--> ConcreteServiceB:exportAction()
```

Comment: I think you are looking for an abstract factory (http://www.masterzendframework.com/servicemanager/configuring-servicemanager-with-abstract-factories/)

Comment: That would be an option if I split my controller class: Every action in that controller would be separated in a single class and gets its own factory... So I can decide in which action I use "ConcreteServiceA" or "ConcreteServiceB" (which then could be created through an abstract factory).

But is there no better way to dynamically exchange the services in my controller after controller was instantiated through his factory? Is it possible to call a factory in a controller and pass an argument to it which decides which service will be instantiated and returned? Maybe with ServiceManager..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a specific action in my controller I want to exchange ConcreteServiceA with ConcreteServiceB to change behavior. Because they have same interface.

You can configure the route to use a different controller *service name* for each action; then configure a controller factory to inject the required service using configuration.

The route config could look like this.

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'foo' => [
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/foo',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'MyControllerWithFooService',
                    'action' => 'actionThatNeedsFooService',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'bar' => [
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/bar',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'MyControllerWithBarService',
                    'action' => 'actionThatNeedsBarService',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Then add the config for the services and controllers.

```
'app_config' => [
    'MyControllerWithFooService' => [
        'service_name' => 'FooService',
    ],
    'MyControllerWithFooService' => [
        'service_name' => 'BarService',
    ],
],
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'FooService' => 'FooServiceFactory'
        'BarService' => 'BarServiceFactory'
    ],
],
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'MyControllerWithFooService' => 'MyControllerServiceFactory'
        'MyControllerWithBarService' => 'MyControllerServiceFactory'
    ],
]
```

The `MyControllerServiceFactory` could be very simple.

```
class MyControllerServiceFactory
{
    public function __invoke($controllerManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $sm = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();

        $config = $sm->get('config');

        if (empty($config['app_config'][$requestedName])) {
            throw new ServiceNotCreatedException('No config set!');
        }

        $serviceName = $config['app_config'][$requestedName]['service_name'];
        $service = $sm->get($serviceName);

        return new MyController($service);
    } 
}
```

Comment: In my opinion a very clean example! Thanks.